# Two monitors in 19.04

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, 19.04

I have two monitors in my computer, but I can get only one to work properly in Ubuntu 19.04.

My video card is an NVIDIA GK107 NVS 510, and I'm using the `nvidia-driver-435` (also tried  X.Org X Server but no luck).

`xrandr` gives me:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

And `lspci | grep VGA` gives me:

```
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 [NVS 510] (rev a1)
```

I also tried purging `nvidia-*` and re-selecting `nvidia-driver-435` under *Additional Drivers* in Software & Updates.

If it helps, when I open the NVIDIA X Server Settings program I don't actually see anything (apart from the quit and help buttons - I tried reinstalling this as well).

Answer (score 1):

If it helps anybody: I re-installed Ubuntu and now it works properly.

It's using the nvidia-driver-418 (not 435 as before). I didn't change anything, Ubuntu chose this automatically now.